# Can I stream audio from Android to Windows through Bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth, audio, windows, streaming

Can I stream audio from Android to Windows through Bluetooth? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can.  Depending on your Bluetooth adapter on your Windows computer.  Connect the two together, find the Phone connection and choose "Control".  There you can connect to the phone as "Music and Audio".

Of course this can be different on your computer and then I cannot help you.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone's coming from a Windows 10 without this feature, I managed to add it by installing Toshiba's Bluetooth Link, for example, from here: http://files.ecp.toshiba.com/2016/08/19/2123/59/tcp0000200a.exe

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 10 versions released before Windows 10 May 2020 Update, Microsoft had implemented support for the A2DP source role, but not for the SINK role for desktop editions. This means you could use Intel Bluetooth on Windows 10 to send audio to other Bluetooth devices, such as a speaker, but you wasn’t be able to receive audio from other Bluetooth devices via A2DP.

Starting in Windows 10 version 2004, Microsoft has re-added the SINK role to Windows 10 for upcoming versions of the OS. However, to use the feature, you need to install a third party app [Bluetooth Audio Receiver](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9N9WCLWDQS5J) from Microsoft Store, as the OS lacks the user interface to activate the SINK role.

The instruction can be found here: [Enable and Use A2DP Sink for Bluetooth in Windows 10](https://winaero.com/enable-and-use-a2dp-sink-for-bluetooth-in-windows-10/)

Comment: Nice start, welcome on the Android SE!

Answer (score 0):

You could use DLNA, this allows to stream Music, Viedeos and Pictures:

- [DLNA - Android/Windows support](http://www.libratone.com/support/use-libratone-zipp/#faq10)
- [MediaServer Android App (Documentation)](http://www.prosyst.com/media/MediaServer/MediaServer-Docu.html)
- [Media Server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=es.mediaserver) (Playstore)

Comment: I couldn't find anything mentioning bluetooth, only wifi

Comment: That's correct: DLNA uses "normal" network ressources. r4d1um probably thought it you main issue to "stream from Android to XX", and "Bluetooth" being an option -- and thus was giving you some other options. It was not that clear that other options were not desired ;)

Comment: I also wouldnt prefer bluetooth to wifi, i guess bluetooth is somehow too slow for streaming audio. But Sorry ive then missunderstood you a bit.

Comment: @r4d1um I would also prefer bluetooth to wifi if it was an option, in my case it probably isn't

Answer (score 0):

I was also frustrated by windows 8 (64bit) with this as well. 
After upgrading from win-7 64bit to win-8 64bit, I was a little miffed to discover that I could no longer connect via Bluetooth to my windows machine and play what was on the phone.

I tried using the software for win-7 from the adapter manufacturer - no good.

So I bought a MediaLink BT (version 4.0) adapter. 
The device instructions say to NOT use the CD, that win-8 will install the necessary drivers. 
--- Drivers installed, BT adapter found and installed, but audio streaming from my phone Still didn't work.

So I tried to let the "autorun" feature of the cd install drivers, but win-8 stopped this saying it was "buggy".

So I "explored" the CD and went to the Vista_Win7>Win64 directory and ran inst.exe.
This installed all of the manufacturers BT stack.

Now when I connect my HTC Vivid (ICS) through Bluetooth to my computer, a "remote control" for my phones media player pops up on the pc desktop and allows me to start the player.

This solved my audio streaming from Android to win-8 64bit problem for $14.99... woot!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, I just did it. I've Android 4.4.2 and WinXP.

Instructions:

1. Enable BT on both devices;
2. Make sure under Windows 'BT Configuration -> Local Services' you have 'Headset' service set to 'Automatic startup';
3. Connect the devices (using pass-phrase if required);
4. Check on Android that 'Media audio' is enabled for the connected PC.

Play some music, enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

in Ubuntu 18.04 is seamless, just pair both then give pc/laptop the role of audio port, then you just play music from the Android. Windows 10 needs some driver that I want to find out