# Use laptop's speakers from phone

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, usb, nexus-5, audio, bluetooth-audio

i was wondering if there is a way to use my laptop's speakers from my Nexus 5 running android 6.0. Basically i want to create play audio files or music from my phone, that could be linked to the laptop through an USB cable, wi fi or bluetooth.
My Pc has windows 10.
Do i need to download any program on my pc or any app on my phone?

Comment: Related: [Can I stream audio from Android to Windows through Bluetooth ?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/39084/can-i-stream-audio-from-android-to-windows-through-bluetooth) ; [Play phone's music wirelessly through computer's speakers](https://superuser.com/questions/641892/play-phones-music-wirelessly-through-computers-speakers) ; [Stream music on Android to Desktop speakers](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17701/stream-music-on-android-to-desktop-speakers) ;

Comment: also; [Can I use my PC as an audio device for my Android phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/39884/can-i-use-my-pc-as-an-audio-device-for-my-android-phone/172024#172024)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you can download SoundWire from the official site